# QUERY versus PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to understand what medium to use to fetch data from a MySQL database using PHP.

What is better "speed" wise, jQUERY or PHP to fetch data form MySQL on page load?

Comment: You can't use jQuery for that anyways.

Comment: You're trying to compare a Server-Side technology to a Client-Side framework.  For JQuery to be able to query MySQL (if even possible) your MySQL Server would have to be publicly accessible

Comment: You could make use of jQuery to perform an AJAX call to a PHP file that handles the processing of data stored in your mySQL database. Please take a look at the jQuery documentation. You could however also use plain JavaScript to perform an AJAX call.

Comment: if i assume, by jquery, if you try to mean it javascript, i think javascript will be marginally faster though probably the difference will be negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery alone you can't fetch data from mysql.
If your question is to load with the page or get the data from php after loading, I can say, that loading with page is better, because the text is standing on the page when you load it and jquery will have a delay to display the data.

```
$.ajax({url: 'ajax.php', success: function(data){$('#name').text(data.name)}});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use jQuery, you ask PHP (or other technology as .NET, ...) to fetch the data from MySQL.

In terms of usability... it depends. Perhaps you want to load your web/application schema and after that use jQuery to load the information (so the web seems to load faster). But, as I said, you will use PHP. The difference is that you can have a PHP file to build the schema and another PHP to retrieve the information.